# Calculating work using potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

wondering if anyone can help me with the following:

"Prove that the force
 $\mathbf{F} = 2xe^{x^{2}}\sin y \ \mathbf{i} + e^{x^{2}}\cos y \ \mathbf{j}$ is conservative, find the potentail and use it to calculate the work by the force along the path from point $(0,0)$ to $(1,{\pi/2})$."

A quick calculation shows $\text{curl} \ \mathbf{F} = 0$, so the force is conservative. Then $\nabla \Phi=\mathbf{F}$, therefore the potential is given by $\Phi=e^{{x}^{2}}\sin y +c$.

The equation of the line joining both points is $\mathbf{r} = t \ \mathbf{i} + \dfrac{\pi}{2}t \ \mathbf{j}$.

So far so good, but for the last question, the usual way to find the work is to calculate:

$\displaystyle \int \mathbf{F} d\mathbf{r}$

What I don't understand is how to find the work using the potential given that it is a scalar function and not a vector one.

Comment: First, it should be $$\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r}$$ Then, considering $$\vec{F} = \nabla \phi \implies \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r} = \nabla \phi \cdot d \vec{r} = \phi_{x} dx + \phi_{y} dy = d \phi$$ you have  $$\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{r} = \int_{C} d \phi = \phi \lvert_{C}$$ where $C$ is the curve, or path, you are integrating along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Phi$ is a potential of $F$, the work is given by

$$ \Phi(1, \frac{\pi}{2})- \Phi(0,0).$$